# Rake task to backup and restore database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am working on a Rails project, and sometimes I program at home and sometimes at work. In my development process, I add data to the database, and I really need a way to synchronize the databases at home and work.

I am thinking about a Rake task to backup/restore the whole database in a Rails app.
Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

write a rake task:

```
namespace :db do
  task :backup do
    system "mysqldump --opt --user=root --password rose userdetails> xyz.sql"
  end

  task :restore do
    system "mysqldump --user=root --password  < xyz.sql"
  end
end
```

By the `rake db:backup` you will get the sql that you can commit to your git/svn and once you work from home to restore pull it and run `rake db:restore`

Comment: This is a good solution, and as an extra bonus, it could read the username/password from the database.yml file.

Comment: The only problem with the restore task is that mysqldump writes a `DROP TABLE` then `CREATE TABLE ...` for each table.  If you write migrations that add tables, and then run the `rake db:restore` without having properly migrated down, the additional tables won't be dropped (since they wouldn't have been written in by mysqldump).  So if you want a "true" restore, you should drop all existing tables first, then load the .sql file.

Answer (score 7):

I use a script that dumps the the database to a particular location, and a second that fetches the dump and uses it to restore a specified database. I use the Whenever gem to schedule daily backups (by calling the first script), by putting this in the schedule.rb file:

```
  every :day, :at => "05:00" do
    command "/var/www/current/script/db_backup.sh -n #{@db_name}"
  end
```

The exact contents of the script depends on what database you're using. As I'm using postgreSQL, the backup script, after figuring the proper location for the dump, runs pg_dump:

```
pg_dump -F t -U username -f file_location<timestamp>.dat database_name
```

And the 'restore' script, which I use to copy the production backup to a local database for testing, uses pg_restore:

```
pg_restore -U username -O -x -d database_name_new path/to/file
```

If you're using some other database, these tools would obviously be different, but most databases support backup and restoration in some form.