# Multiple databases in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, multiple-databases

I'm trying to setup two database for a single Rails Application. The first one is would be the main database and the second would be there in the case the main database would crash. So, I need to manage the two databases (rake db:create, migrate...) and replicate the datas to the second one.
Does anybody know how to do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656080/rake-task-to-backup-and-restore-database should be helpful.

Comment: You should look in to how your RDBMS handles replication, and let that manage your master / backup scheme. Your rails application should not have to worry about handling the replication.

Comment: It's worth noting that [Postgres](http://postgresql.org/) does this [out of the box](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/high-availability.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do that on Application Layer.

Use [keepalived](http://pissedoffadmins.com/general/high-availability-with-keepalived-for-mysql.html) or [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/).